# Simple if IP address is already in the database

Tags: php, mysql

Hey I want to do a simple check when I'm inserting an impression into a database.  I only want to determine if the IP address is already in the database ip field.

In PHP preferably, instead of the the query.

Comment: Just execute the query `SELECT ip FROM table WHERE ip = '$ip'`...  Then check if it returns a row.  Without knowing how you're connecting to the database or your database structure, it's going to be quite hard to give exact code...

Comment: You are asking about how to do the database query? That's impossible to answer without knowing what database library you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$check_ip = (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT ip FROM ip_table WHERE ip='$ip'",$db)) > 0)  ? true : false;`

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the IP adress to an integer using ip2long or the corresponding mysql function.
Then I suggest a table with MyIsam storage engine and a hash index.
If you wan't to be ready for ipv6 you can stoer binary data.
If possible you can also do this in memory tables or apc cache (when you don't need the ip adresses to be stored forever and they can be lost on a server restart).

Comment: MyISAM/InnoDB only support the btree index type.

Comment: Don't you think that's a bit of a premature optimization? As far as we know he may just have some 100 records in the DB and he can just store the IP as a string and be happy with it.

Comment: thats true, but why not do it right in the first place? anyway +1 :D

Answer (score 1):

You're likely to need to use MySQL to determine this (how would PHP know unless it was maintaining its own set of all "known" IP addresses outside of the database?)

You could however, potentially use a single query, most likely via the use of an [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) style query.

i.e.: You'd try the insert anyway, but if there was a duplicate key you'd instead update a view counter, etc. as required.

That said, it's pretty naive to presume that an IP address is unique in any meaningful way, as proxy servers, etc. will effectively hide many users behind a single IP address. Then again, this may not be relevant within your problem domain.